# Get artifact for GAV from Artifactory

Tags: java, artifactory

For given groupId, artifactId, version, classifier and type, how can I download the corresponding artifact using REST?

Comment: from where you want to download it?

Comment: from an artifactory repository.

Answer (score 4):

use the gavc search to get the URL and from there you can download the artefact:

GAVC Search

> Description: Search by Maven coordinates: GroupId, ArtifactId, Version
>   & Classifier. Search must contain at least one argument. Can limit
>   search to specific repositories (local and remote-cache). Since: 2.2.0
>   Security: Requires a privileged user (can be anonymous) Usage: GET
>   /api/search/gavc?[g=groupId][&a=artifactId][&v=version][&c=classifier][&repos=x[,y]]
>
> Headers (Optionally): X-Result-Detail: info (To add all extra
>   information of the found artifact), X-Result-Detail: properties (to
>   get the properties of the found artifact), X-Result-Detail: info,
>   properties (for both). Produces:
>   application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.search.GavcSearchResult+json
>
> Sample Output:

```
GET /api/search/gavc?g=org.acme&a=artifact&v=1.0&c=sources&repos=libs-release-local

{

"results": [

    {

        "uri": "http://localhost:8080/artifactory/api/storage/libs-release-local/org/acme/artifact/1.0/artifact-1.0-sources.jar"

    },{

        "uri": "http://localhost:8080/artifactory/api/storage/libs-release-local/org/acme/artifactB/1.0/artifactB-1.0-sources.jar"

    }

]

}
```

Taken from the [API-Documenation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API).

Comment: Do we know what we can pass as "classifier" in the rest URI? Examples shows: "sources", but what else can we pass. 
I tried passing file extension as matcher, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the Artifactory docs about their REST service you have an example here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveArtifact